# Question for finding two numbers when LCM is given.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher gave me a question at which I am stuck:

> The sum of two positive integers is 52 and their LCM is 168, then what
>   are the numbers?

I studied a concept that the product of LCM and HCF is equal to the product of the numbers, but I am not able to apply that over here.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint. List the factors of 168. They will give you possible values for the two integers. Then check the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: list the divisors of 168, and check which two of them add up to 52. (Of course, you need to check if their LCM is indeed 168; it could be lower.)

There is no formula for this kind of problem, you just have to enumerate the possibilities. In this case, there aren't that many.

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there any other convenient way?

Comment: No, you're lucky that the numbers in this question are quite small.

Comment: Okk thanks a lot

Comment: @codetalker Yep, there's a much more convenient way. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

We see that $168 = 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 7^1$, so we must find two numbers, each of whose prime factorizations has at most three $2$s, at most one $3$, and at most one $7$. Further, at least one of the prime factorizations has to have $2^3$, at least one has to have $3^1$, and at least one has to have $7^1$. Luckily this narrows down the search space considerably.

We eventually notice that $28 = 2^2 \cdot 7^1$ and $24 = 2^3 \cdot 3^1$, and $28 + 24 = 52$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the positive integers be $a$ and $b$ and $a\le b$. Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ so that $\underline{a=dm}$ and $\underline{b=dn}$.

From **Bezout's Theorem**, $\exists x,y\in \Bbb Z:ax+by=d.$ Putting $a=dm$ and $b=dn$, we get
$$\begin{align*}
dm\cdot x+dn\cdot y&=d,\\
\text{or,}\quad\quad\quad\ mx+ny&=1,
\end{align*}$$
$\text{i.e.,}\ \underline{\gcd(m,n)=1}.$ Thus, 
$$a+b=d(m+n)=52=4\cdot13\quad \text{and}\quad \text{lcm}(a,b)=dmn=168=4\cdot2\cdot7\cdot3.$$ But, $\gcd(d(m+n),dmn)=d,$ since $\gcd(m,n)=1.$ Hence, $d=4,$ whence $m+n=13$ and $mn=42.$

Therefore, $m=6,n=7$ and $a=dm=24,b=dn=28.$

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=ua+vb$ and that $$ab=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b).$$ Then try using $b=52-a.$

Then, if $(a,b)=(a,52-a)$ are coprime, then $\gcd(a,52-a)=\gcd(a,52)=1$.
Now, what you should do in a similar exercise would be to first test this assumption, by listing $0<c_i<52$ such that $\gcd(52,c_i)=1$ and plugging them in the equation if they are.

However, here, we saw that the two numbers are not coprime to $52$, and if you plugged them in you would not get an integer from the equation. However, you would then know that $a,b,52$ have at least one common divisor, which would narrow the search.